# using charAt in a program

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is very elementary. The user should enter a name and the program prints only the initials of the name except for the last word.

Eg:

```
input - "Mansha Mannan UL Haque"
output - "M.M.U.Haque"
```

The program is as follows but it does not compile.

```
class joke
{
    public static void main(String str)
    {
        String alter=" "+str;
        int n=alter.length();
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
            char f=alter.charAt(i);
            if (f.compareTo(" ")>0)
            {
                System.out.println(alter.charAt(i+1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error showed is char cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: What error you get when compiling? (Add info to the question)

Comment: f is not string. its char. so you cant use compareTo()

Comment: please format your code correctly

Comment: Once it compiles, it won't run because you don't have valid `main()` method. It should bas `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: havent tested your code, but I noticed that your main class is not public and you should change `String str` to `String[] args`

Comment: What is `f.compareTo(" ")` supposed to do?

Comment: i used String str to take a string (name )from the user. The compare to is used here to compare the character at "i" to a blank space. if there would be a blank space then the letter after the blank space would be printed.

Comment: you must be taking input not passing it to main(), or you are passing your string to main from console.

Comment: there is unnecessary conversion of `char` to `String` and comparison as well. try to change your way of extracting required for more efficient code.

Comment: Thank you all for all your efforts.The correct program is as follows. It took me a long time to find a solution to my mistake. Thanks all.     `class joke { public static void main(String str) { String alter=" "+str; int n=alter.length(); for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { String f=String.valueOf(alter.charAt(i)); if (f.equals(" ")) { System.out.print(alter.charAt(i+1)+"."); } } } }`

Answer (score 0):

Split your input string into string array then access each word and print its first char, for last word print it whole.

```
class joke
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String alter=sc.nextLine(); //take input from user
    String arr[] = alter.split(" ");
    int n=arr.length(); //total words in user string
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        if(i==n-1){   //if last word
             System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
        else{
             System.out.print(arr[i].charAt(0)+". ");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

in this case `name`would be your input

```
  String name = "Mansha Mannan UL Haque";
    String[] nameArray = name.split(" ");
    String newName = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(i != nameArray.length -1)
        {
            newName += nameArray[i].substring(0, 1) + ".";
        }
        else
        {
            newName += nameArray[i];
        }
    }
```

and you should also make your class `joke` public and change `String str` to `String[] args`